# How to replace a substring by another in CN1?

Tags: codenameone

Codename One doesn't support `String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` but only `String.replace(Char, Char)` as indicated here: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-replacing. Is there another simple and efficient way to replace a substring by another?

In my specific case, I need to replace a substring starting and ending as specific positions with an empty string, in other words delete the substring. Tried googling for a solution, but all solutions I came across propose using `String.replace`.

Answer (score 0):

First off you can [file a RFE](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api.html) to add this. There are two versions of replace one of which works with regex and the other works with regular strings. We can probably implement the other. The regex replace might be flaky across platforms.

Right now you can just do:

```
String result = StringUtil.replaceAll("My original String", "original", "new");
```

And the result would be `"My new String"`.